# Can't pass in a full name on the signer when creating the envelope definition

Tags: nuget, docusignapi

Using an almost identical setup to the quickstart project on the docusign site for creating the envelope definition. Nothing is giving me an issue till I tried adding in the full name on the signer object like so,

```
Signer signer = new Signer
        {
            Email = recipientEmail,
            Name = fullName,
            FirstName = recipientFirstName,
            LastName = recipientLastName,
            RecipientId = "1",
            RoutingOrder = "1",
        };
```

For whatever reason when there is a space given in the name I get a 500 back. I am using the latest nuget(5.8.0). If I take out the space then the everything is fine. Unless I am not supposed to use this field, how am I supposed to pass in the full name of the signer?

Adding the full code that I am currently working with,

```
    public string GetSigningUrl(FileItem fileItem, string recipientEmail, string recipientFirstName, string recipientLastName)
    {
        string clientUserId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        EnvelopesApi envelopeApi = CreateEnvelopeApi();
        EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = CreateEnvelope(fileItem, recipientEmail, recipientFirstName, recipientLastName, envelopeApi, clientUserId);
        RecipientViewRequest viewRequest = MakeRecipientViewRequest(recipientEmail, recipientFirstName, clientUserId);

        return envelopeApi.CreateRecipientView(_docuSignAuthorizationService.AccountID, envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId, viewRequest).Url;
    }
    protected EnvelopeDefinition CreateEnvelopDefinition(FileItem fileItem, string recipientEmail, string recipientFirstName, string recipientLastName, ref EnvelopesApi envelopesApi, string clientUserId = null)
    {
        Document document = new Document
        {
            DocumentBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(fileItem.Data),
            Name = "Lorem Ipsum", //fileItem.FileName,
            FileExtension = "pdf", //fileItem.ContentType,
            DocumentId = "1"
        };
        Document[] documents = new Document[] { document };

        Signer signer = new Signer
        {
            Email = recipientEmail,
            Name = $"{recipientFirstName} {recipientLastName}",
            //FullName = $"{recipientFirstName} {recipientLastName}",
            RecipientId = "1",
            RoutingOrder = "1",
        };

        if (clientUserId != null)
            signer.ClientUserId = clientUserId;

        // signing field on the document
        SignHere signHereTab = new SignHere
        {
            DocumentId = "1",
            PageNumber = "1",
            RecipientId = "1",
            TabLabel = "Sign Here Tab",
            XPosition = "195",
            YPosition = "147"
        };
        SignHere[] signHereTabs = new SignHere[] { signHereTab };

        signer.Tabs = new Tabs { SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>(signHereTabs) };
        Signer[] signers = new Signer[] { signer };
        Recipients recipients = new Recipients { Signers = new List<Signer>(signers) };
        EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition
        {
            EmailSubject = "Please sign the document",
            Documents = new List<Document>(documents),
            Recipients = recipients,
            Status = "sent"
        };

        if (envelopesApi == null)
            envelopesApi = CreateEnvelopeApi();
        return envelopeDefinition;
    }

    protected EnvelopeSummary CreateEnvelope(FileItem fileItem, string recipientEmail, string recipientFirstName, string recipientLastName, EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = null, string clientUserId = null)
    {
        EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = CreateEnvelopDefinition(fileItem, recipientEmail, recipientFirstName, recipientLastName, ref envelopesApi, clientUserId);

        EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(_docuSignAuthorizationService.AccountID, envelopeDefinition);
        return results;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 fields in the Signer object and we know it's a bit confusing, but here is me trying to explain:

**Name** - Legal full name, can include middle name, 100 characters max, require field

**FullName** - DocuSign uses that internally to combine first+last.

**FirstName** - Only first name, 50 characters max, optional field.

**LastName**  - Only last name, 50 characters max, optional field.

I tried with spaces in all of these fields with latest nuget for C# and I don't get any error, if you do - can you share the values you used? it may be some other reason

Comment: Thanks for the info! 

I tried it in fullname and I did not receive an error but still get one when putting it under name. 

The values I am using for the names are, 
   "recipientFirstName": "Bob",
   "recipientLastName": "LastName",

And for putting it on the name I'm simply doing string interpolation to combine them, $"{recipientFirstName} {recipientLastName}"

Comment: You don't need FirstName and LastName at all, you can just use Name

Comment: Removed both the first and last name properties from the initializer. So it only populates the name, email, recipient ID and routing order. I still get an error when trying it with both strings for the names in there. 

Unfortunately the debugging information is lacking with a 500 response and the logs showing,
Exception thrown: 'DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException' in DocuSign.eSign.dll
Exception thrown: 'DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly you are putting in the Name property?

Comment: Bob LastName, that is exactly what is going in there

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. If you can provide the exact full code you're running - I can try. I used Name = "Bob LastName" and it worked fine.

Comment: I have updated the post with the code I am using.

Comment: Do you know how to enable API logs? can you do that and see what you get in there?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJYTDcc7cZw

Comment: Apparently I do not have access to that setting, shot a message to get that done by my lead. I will update when i have those logs. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That is a bit odd. Are you using the developer env?

Comment: I found it, I was looking in the wrong place. I enabled the setting and ran my app, but the logs don't seem to be picking up the requests. I am using JWT auth in our app, so could that be why I am not seeing anything from the logs? Though I doubt it, could using that token be causing the weird space issue as well?

Comment: I found the issue. When creating the recipient view request the value getting passing into the username property was a simple constant to put in fake data and not the values I was putting in the request. I just simply overlooked it. 

Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: ok, you didn't explain that your issue is with the second API call to generate a recipient view.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was passing the wrong value into the recipient view request and that was causing the failure since the name did not match the value in the created envelope.

Below is the change that is now in there, where before the value entered into UserName was simply a fake value from a constant and not from my request data.

```
RecipientViewRequest viewRequest = new RecipientViewRequest
        {
            AuthenticationMethod = "none",
            Email = signerEmail,
            UserName = signerName,
            ClientUserId = clientUserId,
            ReturnUrl = _docuSignConfig.RedirectUrl
        };
```